# Google Apps for Domains, Multiple Domains

Tags: email, domain, g-suite

I have a primary google apps for domains account which I use for my personal email, calender, docs etc and is great.

I also receive my pop3 company email via settings->Get mail from other accounts in my account.

Due to spam I want to make use of gmail servers for my company email and have two options:

[1] Add my second domain as a domain alias 
[2] Create a new apps for domains account

If I do [1] above do I access (send and receive) my company email as if it was a separate account or is it merged into my primary domain.  I want the two seperated.

If I perform [2] can I share my contacts / calender between the two?

I also have Act! contact manager which syncs to my primary domain and it is getting messy now with personal and work contacts being changed / sync'd to my Act CM software.  I want to try and separate my personal and work contacts (but make the work them avaiable in my primary domain).

Hope this makes sense!

Your suggestions are gratefully accepted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To answer the parts of your question I can:

If you put the two emails on one apps account then you'll have one inbox and all the messages will come into it.  Though you can use filters to separate them into different labels.

If you use separate accounts, then sharing your calendar is pretty simple, but contacts are a pain.  I've been trying to do this for a while with a google apps account and a gmail account and haven't been able to get my contacts automatically syncing well.

Comment: The problem with sharing an inbox is when you send from the 2nd domain the recipient receives the From domain2.com on behalf of domain1.com which I dont really want.

Comment: Ya - you could make 2 apps accounts and then forward one of them to the other.  

Then you can set it up so it uses an external smtp server.  The external smtp server would just be gmail again, but authenticated with the other email address.  

The end effect is that email2 would get forwarded to email1, so the messages would appear in both email1 and email2 inboxes.  When you sent an email from email2 via your email1 interface, it would use an "external" smtp server so it will appear to only come from email2.  It would also get saved in email2's sent items.

I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: yeah it does..  I have decided to create a new apps for domains account and sync the contacts / share the calender